# UFW - making rules on host to only allow traffic from guest docker containers?

Tags: docker, ufw

Situation:

- host running pgsql
- app in container on host
- want app to connect to database via TCP
- want to configure UFW so only containers on machine can connect to pgsql

What's the best way to do this?
I see ufw we can configure rules based on network device device.
If I run `ip address show`, I can see docker creates some network devices. do i want to build rules based on this?

or do i just make an assumption regarding the docker internal IP address assignment, and make something based on IP ranges like `17.17.0.1/16`?

Neither of these seem like good solutions.

What is the best approach here?